# Qt creator version confusion

Tags: qt

If I go to the Qt creator `Help > About Qt Creator` option, it tells me that

> Qt Creator 3.4.2 (opensource) Based on Qt 5.5.0 (GCC 4.9.1 20140922 (Red Hat 4.9.1-10), 64 bit) )

So is this Qt version of 5 or 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually what @Džanan said is not correct regarding your Qt version.

It means, the version of Qt Creator you have installed is version 3.4.2. The second part `Based on Qt 5.5.0` states that **that** version of Qt Creator was build using Qt 5.5.0, using gcc on Red hat and the IDE is 64 bit.

To find out what version of Qt you are using to build **your** applications with you need to go to "Tools -> Options -> Build & Run -> Qt Versions".

Answer (score -1):

Qt is an `application framework` an Qt Creator is and `IDE`. You have Qt version `5.5.0` and Qt Creator version `3.4.2`. So Qt version is 5 :).

Comment: @Dznan: 1) I installed above qt version in my host system and created app.    2) Using angstrom cross compiler i cross compiled the created app. 3) After cross compilation i copied the executable using pen drive and paste in /opt folder target folder 4) if i run like "./MyApp -qws" , it is successfully running but not display anything , because there is no QWS api for Qt version 5.  5) if i run like "./MyApp -platform eglfs" , getting the error like "QWSSocket::connectToLocalFile could not connect:: Connection refused"  . How to find out exact problem and resolve it. Pls help

Comment: This problem is out of scope of your current question. Create a new one :)